# CouchDB 2.1.0 starts but the REST API keeps unreachable (connection refused)

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm using CouchDB 2.1.0 on my `localhost` to sync the data from a web app. Everything was working until I add a new regular user through the [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) API and sync the remote database (localhost) with the local one (browser storage).

After that, I couldn't access the remote  **_users** database and one of the databases couldn't load even in the list of all databases. I try to refresh Fauxton and, then, it was unreachable.

I tried restarting CouchDB in the terminal and I got no feedback for that. When running `sudo service couchdb status`, everything seems fine, but the REST API and Fauxton are still unavailable.

[image]

When I try to access them in the browser, it gives me an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Any help, please. I'm in the dark here.

I'm using **Linux Mint 18.1 (Ubuntu 16.04 - Xenial)**

Comment: Anything in Couch's logs?

Comment: Hey @AlexisCôté, I was facing the same problem in Ubuntu Xenial and Trusty. I opened an issue on GitHub with the logs from Trusty and they said that it was a bug on CouchDB fixed in version 2.1.1 (https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/970). I removed version 2.1.0 form Xenial, installed a fresh 2.1.1 and it's working since then... In Trusty, however,  the update manager upgraded over the previous 2.1.0 installation and I'm facing another problem now.