# couchdb takes forever to load

Tags: macos, couchdb

I tried to see couchdb from safari "localhost" as I do always.
However, it says it "Loading" until now.
I tried to restart my mac but it still the same.[image]

Can this be fixed?
When I try to access it with python it gave me this error
    error: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Comment: Is it a fauxton problem or a CouchDB problem? (Are you able to access CouchDB with other tools normally?) In your safari  console, do you see any errors?

Comment: I can't access it from both fauxton and python console.

Comment: Might be related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128165/couchdb-2-1-0-starts-but-the-rest-api-keeps-unreachable-connection-refused) Do you have anything in your /var/logs ? Have you try 2.1.1?